# How to restrict 3 api calls per second across 3 partitions in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, rate-limiting

I need to make api calls through databricks. I have 3 partitions. How to restrict 3 api requests per second in databricks? Only 3 request can be posted across 3 partitions at any given time

I am trying to use mappartition and it doesn’t seem to do what I expect

Comment: could you provide an example code? It is not clear what you are trying to do exactly. Are you creating a new column by calling an external API and fetching data on distributed dataset? Additionally, this is not Databricks specific question but Spark.